# How to include the sope datas to generate an access token Oauth2.0?

Tags: php, web-services, curl, oauth, oauth-2.0

I need to generate an access token Oauth2.0 to call a webservice.

My PHP script return an access token but when i call the webservice with this token i have an error code 115 (OAuth access token is not valid).

```
$client_id = 'XXXXX';
$client_secret = 'XXXXX';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'XXXXX/auth/oauth/v2/token' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=client_credentials');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($client_id.':'.$client_secret)));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
```

I tried with postman to generate an access token with the same datas such as my PHP script i have the same error code (115) but when i add the scope datas, the access token generate is now valid to call the webservice.

Do you know how to include the scope datas on my PHP script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a scope request parameter whose value is set a form-encoded list of requested scopes separated by spaces. E.g. to request `read` and `write` scopes you'd use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'scope=read%20write');
```